# empty objects in reducer after dispatch

Tags: promise, react-redux, axios, redux-thunk

I have the following code in my action creator:  this is what I see in reducer - "subData":[{},{},{}]} - in action when I print out it is actually a promise - I tried converting using then but no luck.. have been struggling with all day long...any ideas?

```
    export function getMainData() {
  return async function getMainData(dispatch) {
    const { data } = await getMainDataAPI();
    const subData = data.map((item) => {
      const endpoint = 'build with item.name';
      return Request.get(endpoint);
    });
     console.log('subddd' + subData);  prints -> **[object Promise],[object Promise],[object Promise]**
    dispatch({
      type: GET_DATA_AND_SUBDATA,
      payload: { data, subData }
    });
  };
}

async function getMainDataAPI() {
  const endpoint = 'url';
  return Request.get(endpoint);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [reducer.state.props is undefined in nested actions react/redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47070786/reducer-state-props-is-undefined-in-nested-actions-react-redux)

Answer (score 0):

The question is clearer this time.

Your `console.log` displays a map of 3 promise objects because you didn't wait for the result of your API before going to the next instruction.

Basically you have to use `await Promise.all(data.map(async (item) => {` instead of just `data.map((item) => {`.

Below the working code:

```
export function getMainData() {
  return async function getMainData(dispatch) {
    const { data } = await getMainDataAPI();
    const subData = await Promise.all(data.map(async (item) => {
      const endpoint = 'build with item.name';
      return await Request.get(endpoint);
    }));
    dispatch({
      type: GET_DATA_AND_SUBDATA,
      payload: { data, subData: subData.data }
    });
  };
}

async function getMainDataAPI() {
  const endpoint = 'url';
  return Request.get(endpoint);
}
```

Comment: when I stringify payload in reducer I see only data - no SubData - this time not even empty objects @yuantonito . https://stackoverflow.com/users/4247380/yuantonito

Comment: Can you tell us in your question what you expect your payload to look like and what is the return of every of your API call ? Because in the `Promise.all`, you call 3 times your API so it will return an array and not and object. If you want an object, providing us the expected output will greatly help us

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're dispatching an array of unresolved Promises.  I would try waiting for them to resolve and then dispatch the returned results:

```
...
Promise.all(subData).then(results => {
  dispatch({
    type: GET_DATA_AND_SUBDATA,
    data: { data, subData: results }
  }
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: But I have a map - if I dispatch here I will be dispatching 3 Times (depending up on size of my array)- how Can I add a then to my existing set up is it possible?